# Dealing with lengthy loading of data in a Spinner

Tags: android, rest, server, spinner, adapter

I have two Spinners in Android. A user selects from the first one and then the second Spinner's adapter is populated depending on the selection in the first. The data has to come from a REST server (which is not very fast) and thus the second Spinner takes a long time to load.

What is the best approach for this from a UI point of view? I could do several things, e.g.: show a loading circle where the Spinner is, or disable the second Spinner until the new data is loaded.

These don't seem very optimal solutions and I'd be interested to know if there is a better way to do it.

Note that caching all possible values for all possible selections of the first Spinner before the page is displayed is not really an option as this would require multiple calls to the server and it takes several seconds per call. I have no control over the server or the endpoints provided.

Comment: It would be helpful if this wasn't marked down (and no comment as to why) - it's a legitimate question which is not answered anywhere on SO as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend skeleton style loading.
Only show real controls that are ready to use. So if the first spinner forces an API call. I would use a "cancelable coroutine job" this way it's able to be canceled if they select again.

Then create a skeleton flashing of the second dropdown animating until it's ready. Busy Indicator circles are played out and people hate seeing them.

However, if you are sure you want to do busy indicators circles then I would personally overlay a small busy indicator over the spinner control and make the spinner control not focusable until it is ready.

Also if you implement a repository and MVVM pattern you can hand back cached data while you fetch the updated data if that fits your model.

https://uxdesign.cc/what-you-should-know-about-skeleton-screens-a820c45a571a

Comment: Sounds like a skeleton or placeholder for the second spinner while data is loading might be the way forward.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much you can actually do. If the REST call takes time, well, it takes time, and you can do nothing about it, aside of getting a better Internet connection.

Only thing that cames to my mind is to take al the possible choices in the second Spinner at application loading, and store it locally in a database. This way, maybe it will take time to load the app only the first time it is used, but the next executions will be faster, since you dont need to re-download the data.

Or, simply, just show a loading circle. If the REST servicer is slow, it is not your fault...

Comment: Yes, I was hoping there might be a standard way for this - none of the apps I have show an example of this situation.  I was wanting a way to avoid having the user select from the second spinner before it had loaded the new data.